# Windows 7 (DirectWrite) text-rendering comparison

Tags: windows-7, windows, cleartype

Windows 7 apparently has [advances in its text rendering](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/02/13/advances-in-typography-and-text-rendering-in-windows-7.aspx) through the new DirectWrite API. It sounds to me like DirectWrite is employing a more OS X Quartz style of text rendering; MS call it *Natural ClearType*. However, because taking advantage of the new rendering requires use of the new API, I've not been able to do any comparisons.

**Does know of any apps/tool/demos on Windows 7 that take advantage of these new features?**

**Failing that, does anyone know of any screenshots or other samples?**

*note: I've already found the demos [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/graphics/article.php/c16139/) and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC18/) (16 minutes onwards).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are samples included with the [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6db1f17f-5f1e-4e54-a331-c32285cdde0c) that are fully compilable if you would like to play around with them.

Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's awesome thanks. What I'm really after are some comparisons of normal ClearType vs. DirectWrite enhanced "Natural ClearType". I don't think the DirectWrite_Demo1 shows that off too well, and I have absolutely no clue as to how to modify the demos myself.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 37 takes advantage of it. See http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/chrome-37-beta-directwrite-on-windows.html